# Access violation writing newly allocated memory

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have a program that **intermittently** crashes with "access violation" when running for **long periods of time**. Having debugged it I came across a very strange phenomenon.

The program crashes on a code that assigns (copies) one `std::vector` to another, like this:

```
struct Data
{
int int1;
int int2;
}
//vec1 is empty
//vec2 contains a couple of thousands Data structs 
std::vector<struct Data> vec1 = vec2;//**crash happens here**
```

What happens is simple - STL allocates a memory block for `vec1`, and the data from `vec2` is copied there. Allocation goes fine. Crash happens on the copy process, when STL tries to fill the newly allocated memory for `vec1` with the data from `vec2`. 
What's even more strange, is that some part of that copy process is properly executed, and crash happens somewhere in the middle of that process.

My question is - how can a newly allocated memory block be "partly" non-writable? Thank you.

**EDIT: guys, I don't say that this code has problem - it certainly doesn't. I'm asking why can such type of code crash? I.e. how can the other part of my program modify the memory block that is newly allocated by STL? And how can one debug such memory corruption?**

And yes, this is the real code

Addition: I've enabled **page heap** to see if the problem happened before this code was executed. It didn't catch anything.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else... maybe there's a dangling pointer or something like that somewhere.

Comment: Is that literally what the `Data` struct looks like? If so, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When the free store has been corrupted, pretty much anything can happen. This kind of problem is nasty to track down, because the corruption occurred somewhere **before** it showed symptoms.

Comment: -1 the code you have shown has no bearing on the problem, since it's **not real code**. all that it tells us is what your misperception of the code is, not what the code is.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how Data looks like. I'm also thinking the problem is somewhere else, but any ideas how can this happen, and how can I find the problem?

Comment: We are not getting the full picture here,

Comment: I cannot compile the programm. My compiler says "error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token".

Comment: can you provide a small compilable example?

Comment: @Agentlien - Do not hold your breath.

Comment: "how can the other part of my program modify the memory block that is newly allocated by STL?" -- at this point of your code, the heap is already corrupted, so any attempt to allocate memory would cause crash.

Comment: Igor, allocation goes fine, it's the copy process that results in access violation

Comment: Besides, I mentioned that Page heap is enabled and catches nothing, so it's not that heap is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found that the reason was improper synchronization, i.e. `vec2` was modified from a secondary thread while `vec1` was in initialization process. STL code that corresponds to the vector assignment in the original post is following:

```
if (_Buy(_Right.size())) 
    _Mylast = _Ucopy(_Right._Myfirst, _Right._Mylast, _Myfirst);
```

First line allocates memory for the new vector, and the second copies the content.

What was happening is after first line was done (and memory allocated), the vector was modified from outside thread and its size was increased. So the second line was trying to copy more elements than allocated memory size. This led to access violation.